# Get header title from static table view

Tags: iphone, static, header, uitableview, subclass

I am using a static grouped UITableView to display some settings to the user. Above each group I have a header with a title.

I want to customize the look of the table view and I want to use this look throughout the whole application. Therefore I have subclassed the UITableViewController and my TableViewControllers are inheriting from my subclass.

Is there a way to enter a title for a header using Interface Builder and in my UITableViewController subclass change the look of the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried retrieving the title using `[self tableView:self.tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section]` but quickly after posting this question I realized it should have been called from `super`. Therefore:

`[super tableView:self.tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section]`.

The header can be customized using

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *title = [super tableView:self.tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];

    if (title.length == 0) return nil;

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 40)];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.text = title;

    return label;
}
```